# How do I manipulate an integer variable through two different while loops?

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble writing code that will execute through the one loop while it is odd and through another loop if it is even. Here is my code so far:

public class Sequence {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Please Enter an positive integer no more than 100: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int initial = input.nextInt();

    if (initial >= 100 || initial <= 0) {
        System.out.println("The input is invalid");

    }

    if (initial % 2 == 0) {
        while (initial % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print("[" + initial + "] ");
            initial = initial / 2;

        }
    }
    if (initial % 2 == 1) {
        while (initial % 2 == 1) {
        System.out.print("(" + initial + ") ");
        initial = 6 * initial + 2;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you post what it is printing, and what you want it to print . Maybe you need a 'else'  .

Comment: What happens when you run this code and how does the output differ from what you want?

Comment: Also, you should step away from the computer and get a pencil and paper. Write **in words** the steps you need to take to solve the problem. Feel free to use words like `if` and `while` which correspond to Java keywords, but don't worry about the exact syntax. Just concentrate on the logic of the steps needed.

Comment: a/ I think the usual formula is *3+1, (which is just twice what you use, so that just removes one step). b/ you don't need those 2 loops. c/ you need to define what is the exit condition of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code will help your need

```
private static int handleOddNo(int oddNo){
    int initial = oddNo;
    while (initial % 2 == 1) {
        System.out.print("(" + initial + ") ");
        initial = 6 * initial + 2;
        if(initial == 1)
            break;
    }
    return initial;
}

private static int handleEvenNo(int evenNo){
    int initial = evenNo;
    while (initial % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print("[" + initial + "] ");
        initial = initial / 2;
        if(initial == 1)
            break;
    }
    return initial;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Welcome to The Sequence Generator");

    System.out.println("---------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Please Enter an positive integer no more than 100: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int initial = input.nextInt();

    if (initial >= 100 || initial <= 0) {
        System.out.println("The input is invalid");

    }
    do{
        if (initial % 2 == 0) {
            initial = handleEvenNo(initial);
        }else{
            initial = handleOddNo(initial);
        }
    }while(initial != 1);

}
```

Comment: God bless you and your family

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be illustrated with `5` as an input. Since this is odd, you completely skip the even case and then continue to calculate `6 * 5 + 2` which is `32`. I assume that you now want to treat return to the even case and continue calculating. Note that this implies that you need a loop. In other words, you should put an if statement inside a while loop. Your current logic is the exact reverse of this.